# Is there a way to input columns into a db iteratively with python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
def db_include(path, filename):
    full_file_path = path + filename
    patterns = pattern_retrieval(full_file_path)
    db_file = 'sequencesdb.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        columns = list()
        columns_data = list()
        #create table
        for key, value in patterns.items():
            columns.append(key)
            columns_data.append(value)
        #create column names
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sequences ()''')
```

> The pattern_retrieval function returns a dictionary

> The dictionary is stored in patterns variable

> now I want to create a table called sequences in sequences.db but I want each column to have the name of a key in the patterns variable.This is to help me then insert ints into each column after creating the db.

PATTERNS_DB SCHEMA

sequences table

|pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|

|42      | 67     |  78

But I want to do all this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

- After trial and error, I think the best thing to do is to  first run

```py
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sequences(EMPTY TEXT)''')
```

- to create a the table with a default column which can be deleted later
  then run

```py
for i in range(len(columns)):
    addColum = f"ALTER TABLE sequences ADD COLUMN {columns[i] INTEGER}"
    c.execute(addColumn)
    conn.commit()
```